# What is a good technique for finding where copies of my class are being made in optimized code?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've got a class that's both copyable/movable and I'd like to find any places in my code where a copy is being made, to make sure that I can't replace them with a move for performance.  Does anyone know of a good technique to essentially list all the copies being made in my final *optimized* code?

Comment: I've done this with a standard profiler. The copy constructor stood out in the profile for a certain hot function.

Comment: And idea how to do it statically?

Comment: It is unlikely that this can be done statically. The only reliable way to detect this is to delete the copy constructor and the assignment operator, recompile the code, and have the compiler find all instances, for you.

Comment: are you stuct with c++11? With c++17 you have mandatory copy elision which - depending on what your copy constructor does - might allow you to delete it.

Comment: You could temporarily `= delete` the copy-constructor and/or assignment-operator, and see if you can leverage your move-constructor and/or move-assignment-operator.  Not sure if it is a "good" technique, but it is a technique, and leverages the compiler generating errors for where the deleted things would otherwise be used.